# Validating input in a form in Java using a Validate class. I am trying to get the code to use the Validate class into my program

Tags: java

I have written a Validate class using Java and I want to use it to validate input on a form. The form itself is written and works. the following is an example of the code from my Validate class:

```
public static boolean validateID( String ID){

     return ID.matches("\\d{5}");
}
```

then I try to put the corresponding code into the form code

```
if(!Validate.validateID(ID)){
 System.out.println("Please enter a 5 digit number for the ID");
```

}

I keep getting the following error message and can't figure out how to fix it.

incompatible types: JTextField cannot be  converted to a String.

Comment: `ID` might be a `JTextField`. Check the variable type of `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the type of ID that you are passing in is a variable of JTextField and not String. You didn't provide us with the declaration or initialization of ID so can't really pinpoint it.

Comment: Hi this is the code for the ID declaration     
    private void IDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
       
         ID.setText("");
   
    }

Comment: I don't understand. In validateId( String ID ), you are saying that the method accepts a variable of type String to be passed into it. 

But you are passing in a JTextField named ID, not a String. Where do you define the variable called ID that you are using here?
`if (!Validate.validateID( **** THIS ONE -> ID <- ****)`

Comment: private javax.swing.JTextField ID;

Comment: So what are you confused about then? validateID wants a String input and you are inputting a jTextField ... not sure what else to tell you.